# SQL error: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, parameters

This is my code. I believe it does not bind the value's to the parameters.. But I don't know why:

```
public function create($fields)
    {
        $keys = array_keys($fields);
        $values = null;
        $x = 1;

        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $values .= '?';
            if ($x < count($fields)) {
                $values .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

        if(!$this->db->prepare($sql)->execute($fields)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And on index.php:

```
$user = new User();
$user->create(array(
                'name' => 'test',
                'username' => 'test2',
                'email' => 'test@gmail.com'
            ));
```

Why are my values not bound to the parameters? This is the full error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO users (`name`,
>   `username`, `email`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["test", "test2",
>   "test@gmail.com"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) your syntax is wrong here i think

Comment: @Lex de Willigen Yes you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the **`?`** way for your query, the array that you send in params might **not have keys** i think!

EDIT: do **`execute(array_values($fields))`**, you must use the keys when there are params like *`username = :username, pass = :pass`* etc

Comment: so, please give me a solution? And I believe there are keys, since they are filled in in the first part of the query: 'name' 'username' 'email'

Comment: That did the job! Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

### Try This

```
    public function create($fields)
        {
            $keys ='';
            $values = '';
            foreach($fields as $k=>$field) {
                $keys[] = $k;
                $values[] = $field;
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (".implode(',',$keys).") VALUES ("'".implode ("','",$values)."'")";
            if(!$this->db->prepare($sql)->execute($fields)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```